# как получить данные из класса ActiveRecords Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

вот такой код возвращает объект ActiveRecords

```
$actual_devices = ClientsDaily::find()
            ->select('clients_daily.id')
            ->leftJoin('devices_daily', 'clients_daily.id = devices_daily.client_id')
            ->where(['devices_daily.active = 1'])
            ->andWhere(['devices_daily.server > 0'])
            ->andWhere(['devices_daily.paid = 1'])
            ->andWhere(['clients_daily.id = '.$id]);
```

как получить данные?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$actual_devices = ClientsDaily::find()
          ->select('clients_daily.id')
          ->leftJoin('devices_daily', 'clients_daily.id = devices_daily.client_id')
          ->where(['devices_daily.active' => 1])
          ->andWhere(['>','devices_daily.server',0])
          ->andWhere(['devices_daily.paid' => 1])
          ->andWhere(['clients_daily.id' => $id])
          ->all();
```

[Мануал](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-active-record/#querying-data)

Comment: KhonkoТак ошибка Invalid Argument – yii\base\InvalidArgumentException
Operator 'DEVICES_DAILY.ACTIVE = 1' requires two operands.

Comment: @Dmitriy поправил свой ответ, попробуйте сейчас